# Unity run-time resolving?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I have the following code in a console program.

```
interface I { ...; string X { get; }; string Y {get; }; string Z {get; } ...}
class A : I {...}
class B : I {...}
class C : I {...}
```

The program accept command line parameters like `test.exe b -x 10 -z 20`. And it will create an instant of B and set X to 10, Z to 20.

How to implement this using unity? This may be a newbie question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register named mapping against same interface and resolve using the name passed as argument.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<I, A>("a");
container.RegisterType<I, B>("b");
container.RegisterType<I, C>("c");

I instance = container.Resolve<I>(args[0]);
```

Read [Registering Type Mappings with the Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx#registertype_simple) for explanation

Comment: ... and then move on and set the X,Y,Z properties on instance to the other args...